# Azure Yaml DevOps variable handling

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

So I have a YAML file where I am trying to do something like the following:

```
# top of the file, declare global variables
variables:
- name: MyName
  value: 'apple'
...

parameters:
- name: SwitchName
  type: boolean
  default: false
...


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  ...

  jobs:
    variables:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.SwitchName, true) }}:
      - name: MyName
        value: '$(MyName)_pie'
    ...

    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@1
         inputs:
           scriptType: inlineScript
           inlineScript: |
             Write-Output $(MyName)
...
#end of script
```

The goal is to control the pipeline to print `apple` in default run and `apple_pie` when the user selects that parameter in the UI to be true.

I understand that parameters are compile-time and variables are run-time. I know that to overwrite a global variable you can create a variable at a job level and change it as yo see fit. Sadly, the way how template works do not let me redeclare that variable properly and I end up with `$(MyName)_pie`. For some reason, Yaml fails to see that inside that template there is a runtime variable that is needed to be defined.

What are my options here to achieve desired behavior?
Anything missing in my understanding here?

Comment: *variables are run-time*. Not necessarily. Run-time variables are accessed using `$[ variables.foo ]` syntax. You actually *are* using compile-time variables here. However, I think you're seeing an artifact of ordering of variable resolution. Did you try `variables.MyName` syntax, or `${{ variables.MyName }}`, or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to use the `${{ variables.MyName }}` to call the variable in root level.

For example:

```
variables:
- name: MyName
  value: 'apple'


parameters:
- name: SwitchName
  type: boolean
  default: false



stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:
   - job: A
     variables:
     - ${{ if eq(parameters.SwitchName, true) }}:
       - name: MyName
         value: '${{ variables.MyName }}_pie'
     steps:
       - script: "echo $(MyName)"
```

**Result:**

[image]

Since you used an if expression to reassign value, the variable will be assigned at compile time.

Refer to this doc: [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)

You can use the template expression format: `${{ variables.var }}`

Comment: Great, that worked, I don't know why I could not figure it out from docs.